# Can you tell MySQL to store a database at a specific location

Tags: mysql

I know that "by default" MySQL stores all databases in the same directory. Is there a way to tell MySQL to put a specific database in a different directory (the idea being to protect this directory with some encryption like Veracrypt)?

Louis

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the datafile location [for a given table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-create-table-external.html).

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY = '/external/directory';
```

You can specify an absolute pathname to the datafile for a [general tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-tablespaces.html), then use that tablespace for several tables.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE `ts1` ADD DATAFILE '/my/tablespace/directory/ts1.ibd' Engine=InnoDB;
```

You can also [use symbolic links](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/symbolic-links.html) to locate an entire subdirectory for a schema on another location outside the default data directory. All tables within that schema (if you use `innodb_file_per_table` or general tablespaces) will be in the directory pointed to by that symbolic link.